# Dimension of the intersection of $2$ subspaces: $\dim(W \cap X) \leq \min \{\dim(W), \dim(X)\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space, $W$ a subspace of $V$, and $X$ another subspace of $V$.
Prove that
$$
\dim(W \cap X) \leq \min \{\dim(W), \dim(X)\}.
$$

I'm not sure the best way to prove it. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to figure out the dimension of a space?

Comment: $W\cap X$ is a subspace of both $W$ and $X$…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W \cap X \subseteq W$ and $W \cap X \subseteq X$. So, any basis for $W$ spans $W \cap X$. Hence, the dimension of $W \cap X$ is at most the dimension of $W$.

The same applies for $X$, and the result follows immediately.

Comment: Thank you Fred, let me think about it. Still learning the new concept.

Comment: @MillikenFarmer let me know if you need further clarification or guidance

Comment: If basis for W spans W∩X, then dim(W∩X) <= dim(W), I can not find any theorem base on 2 weeks of course learning. Could you please advise the theorem name? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MillikenFarmer this is simply the definition of a basis: a linearly independent spanning set. The dimension of a vector space is the size of a basis, and a basis is a maximal linearly independent set (you can prove this, again from the definition of a basis). So, if we have a spanning set for a vector space, it must be at least as big as a basis for that space, and the result follows.

Comment: thanks a lot, now I can understand it, it makes sense. Have a good evening!

Comment: You are welcome - if your question has been answered, you can mark it as such